# Update de campo json com select na mesma tabela PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Tenho uma tabela em que tenho que pegar dados de um registro e fazer o update em uma coluna de outro registro da mesma tabela. Esses campos são do tipo `json`.

Eu consegui pegar os dados para serem inseridos mas não estou conseguindo fazer o *update* no outro registro

```
select json_build_object(
        'one_signal',json_build_object(
            'oneSignalAppId', conf_json::jsonb->'oneSignalAppId',   
            'oneSignalAutoRegister', conf_json::jsonb->'oneSignalAutoRegister' 
        )       
    )::jsonb    
from config 
join loja
    on loja.loja_id = config.loja_id
    where conf_tipo = 6 and (conf_json::jsonb->'oneSignalAppId')::text != 'null'
```

Esse `SQL` retorna isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A coluna que deve receber esse json possui esses dados

```
{  
    "teste": {
        "ativo": true,
        "value": null
   },
     "resources": {
        "resources": {
            "urlLogoSite": "logo.png",
            "urlFaviconSite": null,
            "urlFooterPadraoEmail": null,
            "urlHeaderPadraoEmail": null
        }
    }
}
```

E após o update ela deveria ficar assim:

```
{  
    "teste": {
        "ativo": true,
        "value": null
   },
     "resources": {
        "resources": {
            "urlLogoSite": "logo.png",
            "urlFaviconSite": null,
            "urlFooterPadraoEmail": null,
            "urlHeaderPadraoEmail": null
        }
    },
    "one_signal":{
          "oneSignalAppId": "6ac1c27c-7b17-4645-b5d2-098be724b52e", 
          "oneSignalAutoRegister": true
    }

}
```

O banco que eu estou usando é o `PostgreSQL 9.4`. Para fazer o *update* tentei usar o `json_object_agg` mas não consegui juntar os dados atuais com os dados do *select*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

```
UPDATE config SET conf_json = (
    SELECT json_object_agg(key, value)::jsonb
        FROM (
            WITH to_merge AS (
                SELECT * FROM jsonb_each((
                    SELECT (conf_json)::jsonb
                        FROM config
                    JOIN loja
                        ON loja.loja_id = config.loja_id
                    WHERE conf_tipo = 19)
                )
            )
            SELECT * FROM jsonb_each((
                SELECT json_build_object(
                        'one_signal',json_build_object(
                        'appId', conf_json::jsonb->'oneSignalAppId',   
                        'autoRegister', conf_json::jsonb->'oneSignalAutoRegister' 
                    )       
                )::jsonb    
                FROM config 
                    JOIN loja
                        ON loja.loja_id = config.loja_id
                    WHERE conf_tipo = 6 AND (conf_json::jsonb->'oneSignalAppId')::text != 'null' )
            )
        WHERE key NOT IN (SELECT key FROM to_merge)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM to_merge
    ) t)
WHERE conf_tipo = 19
```